# hooks is called conditionally compiling error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, intellij-idea, react-redux, react-hooks

```
  Line 15:3:  React Hook "useEventListener" is called conditionally. React Hooks must be called in the exact same order in every component render. Did you accidentally call a React Hook after an early return?  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
```

Hi
when I am trying to run the below code on `local` I am getting the above error, but online editor compile successfully? why?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-8o8dib?file=index.js

```
import { useCallback } from 'react';
import useEventListener from './useEventListener';

const ESCAPE_KEY = 27;

const useEscape = (callback, disabled = false) => {
  if (disabled) return;

  const handleEscapePress = (event) => {
    if (event.keyCode === ESCAPE_KEY) {
      callback(event);
    }
  };

  useEventListener('keydown', handleEscapePress);
};

export default useEscape;
```

I am using `intellij webstrom`.

Comment: `if (disabled) return;` conditionally allows the `useEventListener` to be called.

Comment: how to fiix this

Comment: @DrewReese any idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issue

You conditionally return early, so the `useEventListener` isn't called/invoked every render cycle.

## Solution

Seems `disabled` is used to prohibit the callback from firing, so put the condition on that instead.

```
import useEventListener from './useEventListener';

const ESCAPE_KEY = 27;

const useEscape = (callback, disabled = false) => {
  const handleEscapePress = (event) => {
    if (event.keyCode === ESCAPE_KEY) {
      !disabled && callback(event);
    }
  };

  useEventListener('keydown', handleEscapePress);
};

export default useEscape;
```

Comment: correct answer ...!! why online editor is not giving ths error?

Comment: @user944513 What online editor? It may not be running the same linter create-react-app does by default. Try codesandbox, it has react templates and provides nearly the same experience as vscode, but it's in the web.

Comment: see https://codesandbox.io/s/hooks-q2zoq?file=/src/DropdownMenu.js:551-694

Comment: see `useEscape` it is not giving any compiling error

Comment: @user944513 Expand the console and look in the "Problems" tab, the eslint issue is listed there. Also, in the editor window `useEventListener has been code highlighted (red squiggly underline) with the issue, if you hover over it it also displays the issue in a tooltip.